# How to know which conda interpreter I'm using with messy output?

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda

Sorry for the wording here as I'm not familiar with the concepts here. Please point out and I will correct.

## Background

Prior to my installation of anaconda, I ran `which conda`, I get `/usr/bin/conda`. This is not what I wanted to use. So, I installed my own conda by following this [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart). After installation, I ran `conda init`. I then added to `~/.bashrc`, 
`export PATH=/home/my_name/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`, and uncommented it off. After all this, when I ran `which conda`. I get the following,

```
{
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA;
    else
        \local cmd="$1";
        shift;
        case "$cmd" in
            activate | deactivate)
                __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@"
            ;;
            install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall)
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@" && __conda_reactivate
            ;;
            *)
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
            ;;
        esac;
    fi
}
```

## Problem

How to interpret the printed result? Had I been successful in substituting the `conda` I'm using?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One should not manually add Anaconda/Miniconda to PATH - `conda init` already adds code to handle this case.

Comment: @merv Thanks. Got it